# Generating equivalent method without list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a bit confused with list comprehension in Python. I just learned Python 3 months ago and hope to improve. I have the following method:

```
def func(self, n):
    Arr = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 16) for _ in range(n)]
    Arr = list(set(Arr))
    Arr = [('{0:0' + str(16) + 'b}').format(x) for x in Arr]
    Arr = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in Arr])
    return Arr
```

I want to generate its equivalent one by flattening the list comprehension. I did the following:

```
def func(self, n):
    Arr = []
    for _ in range(n):
        Arr.append(random.randint(0, 2 ** 16))
    Arr = list(set(Arr))

    for x in Arr: # This loop has an issue
        Arr.append(('{0:0' + str(16) + 'b}').format(x))

    for x in Arr: # This loop has an issue
        Arr.asarray([list(map(int, list(x)))])
    return Arr
```

I still have a problem in the second and third loops. Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: Try printing `Arr` after each loop (including the first one) to find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't append to the lists while iterating them; the loop will only go on forever.

Instead, update the item at each index using list subscription:

```
for i in range(len(Arr)):
    Arr[i] = '{0:016b}'.format(Arr[i])
```

Needless to say that the *list comprehension* is far more **elegant** and much easier to read and probably understand than the naive *for* loop.

Comment: Not forever, only until they run out of memory :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well that's assuming they aren't running their code on a Turing machine :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try the last loop by my self

Comment: @Lauren For the second loop, process all the items first and then convert to a `np.array` after looping.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye So sweet. Thank you for the hint. The reason why I want to "decompose" the loops is because I want to make my code easier to be parallelised for future work.